# Changing default browser for WiFi landing page in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, wifi

When connecting to a WiFi network with a landing page in OS X Lion, a popup Safari browser window will open up with the landing page.

Is there any way to change the browser used for this? (Changing to chrome for example, will enable me to save WiFi login credentials).

Answer (score 0):

You should go to Safari -> Preferences -> General.

Choose Chrome as your default browser. This should (Hopefully) change the landing page.

Comment: I don't understand this. How can I choose Chrome as a default browser under the settings of another browser?